# How to create dictionary of dictionaries vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries in VBS, and I can get it to work; however, it seems that my sub level dictionary is being accessed by reference instead of by value?

I tried this:

```
Dim s, fso, f, ts, str, fRead, line, i, dictElements, dictionary, screenItem
Set s = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dictElements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'add elements to dictionary
dictElements.Add "Name", "MyName"
dictElements.Add "Setpoint", 100.0
dictElements.Add "Process Value", 80.6

'Create Data Structure
dictionary.Add "DigitalInputOne", dictElements
dictionary.Add "DigitalInputTwo", dictElements

'test dictionary
dictionary("DigitalInputTwo")("Name")= "Hello"
dictionary("DigitalInputTwo")("Setpoint")= 40.123
HmiRuntime.Screens("Home").ScreenItems("Text field_1").Text = dictionary ("DigitalInputOne")("Name")
HmiRuntime.Screens("Home").ScreenItems("Text field_2").Text = dictionary("DigitalInputOne")("Setpoint")
HmiRuntime.Screens("Home").ScreenItems("Text field_3").Text = dictionary("DigitalInputOne")("Process Value")

HmiRuntime.Screens("Home").ScreenItems("Text field_4").Text = dictionary("DigitalInputTwo")("Name")
HmiRuntime.Screens("Home").ScreenItems("Text field_5").Text = dictionary("DigitalInputTwo")("Setpoint")
HmiRuntime.Screens("Home").ScreenItems("Text field_6").Text = dictionary("DigitalInputTwo")("Process Value")
```

When I change one of the values it changes all of the values, which makes me think my elements dictionary is by reference.  Is there a way to make this happen by value?  I want each sub dictionary to be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have

```
Set dictElements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

once so you are only creating one subdictionary -- and are setting two keys to point to that one subdictionary. Instead, do the following:

```
Set dictElements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create first sub-dict
dictionary.Add "DigitalInputOne", dictElements
Set dictElements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create second sub-dict
dictionary.Add "DigitalInputTwo", dictElements
```

VBScript has reference-counting based garbage collection. When you add the first dictionary to the top-level dictionary, the top level dictionary now maintains a reference to it. Thus, when you set `dictElements` equal to a second dictionary, the original dictionary is kept alive by the top-level dictionary, hence it isn't garbage-collected.

Comment: Will this allow me to create a template, or is there a better way to do that?  Most of my subdictionaries will be the same, only with different values.

Comment: I would write a sub which, when passed a dictionary, initializes it in a certain way. Then follow the 3-step process: 1) create the dictionary, 2) run the initialization sub on it, 3) assign it to the top-level dictionary.

Comment: I wanted to use dictElements basically like a data type.  I did this, and it works 
`Set dictionary("DigitalInputOne") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictionary("DigitalInputTwo") = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each item In dictionary
    For Each element In dictElements
        dictionary(item).Add element, dictElements(element)
    Next
Next` but I don't think it's very good.  I can't use classes because I'm doing this in WinCC.

Comment: Ok.  That's what I just started doing and it works.  I didn't know if there was a better way or not.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would use a `Class` for this and have a `Dictionary` of `Class` objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, VBScript's dictionary object lacks a clone method. You can actually use some .Net containers in VBScript, maybe something like `CreateObject("System.Collections.HashTable")` could be used to create a cloneable hashtable that can be used as a template.

Comment: @JohnColeman I was referring to the VBScript `Class` structure that allows you to build your own objects that you can then store in a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: @Lankymart I realize that (I was actually the one who upvoted your comment) -- my last comment was directed to OP's question of whether or not there was a better way. A built-in clone method would be ideal for implementing a template-dictionary, but unfortunately there isn't any such thing in straight VBScript.

Comment: @JohnColeman no problem just wasn't sure if it was in reply to my comment.

Comment: @Lankymart You are correct that a custom class provides a good solution to OP's problem. If you flesh out the idea and add it as a second answer I would gladly upvote it.